# Passing few arguments via getopt

Tags: c, command-line, getopt

What I want to do is to get more arguments from the command line and get them output each one on a new line. How could I do that by keeping the same structure? I want also to get the -f output.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nod1, opt;
    int nsecs, nod2;

   nsecs = 0;
    nod2 = 0;
    nod1 = 0;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "nf:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'n':
            nod1 = 1;
            break;
        case 'f':
            nsecs = atoi(optarg);
            nod2 = 1;
            break;
        default: /* '?' */
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-t nsecs] [-n] name\n",
                    argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

   printf("nod1=%d; nod2=%d; optind=%d\n", nod1, nod2, optind);

   if (optind >= argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument after options\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   printf("Output = %s\n", argv[optind]);

   /* Other code omitted */

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

From a comment:

> The arguments after the `-f` should be optional and I want to list every single one that has been passed under one another...
>
> ```
> $ ./partitioner -n 4 -f Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4
> Number:4
> File names:
> Output = Test1
> Output = Test2
> Output = Test3
> Output = Test4
> $
> ```

Comment: I suggest including the correct usage message after reporting things like 'expected argument after options'.  It helps people get the correct usage. It is also a good idea if your usage message (which mentions `-t`) matches what `getopt()` expects (which is `-f`).

Comment: POSIX [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) doesn't really handle optional arguments sensibly.  GNU `getopt()` is a bit better, but not by much.  Avoid them whenever you can. The sample usage I copied up from the comment doesn't match the usage, even if the `-f` vs `-t` issue is resolved.  You have an argument `4` after `-n` which takes no argument. In classic (POSIX) `getopt()`, that would end the options. GNU `getopt()` permutes options and arguments unless you have POSIXLY_CORRECT in the environment or use the correct mark to start the options.

Comment: At the moment, I've voted 'close — unclear what you are asking'.  Make a comment to me (@Jonathan) after you've clarified what you want to achieve and I'll revisit (and remove this comment).

Answer (score 0):

Having in account the comment made by  Jonathan Leffler I edit my answer:

> *POSIX getopt() doesn't really handle optional arguments sensibly. GNU getopt() is a bit better, but not by much. Avoid them whenever you can.*

I come out with a simple idea, but one that could solve your problem so here it is:

In `argv` you have a list of arguments ordered as they was in the commend line right? So, if you can find any `-f` in `argv` that means all arguments following `-f` until another option or the end of the argument list are the options you want to print.

From `-f` to another option(-g in this case):

> ./command  -a A -b B -f **one two tree** -g G

From `-f` to the end.

> ./command  -a A -b B -f **one two tree**

Here you have a helper function for doing that:

```
bool get_f_args(int argc, char *argv[], int &count, int* indexes)
{
    bool f_found = false, parsing_f_args = false;
    int collect_count = 0;

    if (argc < 3) return false;  // "./command -f" are just two values for argv
                                 // we need at least 3.

    // Check for every argument in the argument list.
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {

        // If you found another option
        // stop collecting args.
        if (argv[i][0] == '-' && parsing_f_args)   // options starts with '-' character.
            parsing_f_args = false;

        if (parsing_f_args)
            indexes[count++] = i;

        // If some is "-f" then the following are the 
        // ones you're looking for. We check for -f after
        //
        // indexes[count++] = i; 
        //
        // in roder to avoid adding -f index to indexes.
        if (strcmp("-f", argv[i]) == 0) { 
            parsing_f_args = true;
            f_found = true;
        }

    }
    return f_found;
}
```

And here is an example of use:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int count = 0; 
    int indexes[10];

    bool f_found = get_f_args(argc, argv, count, indexes);
    if (f_found){
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            printf("Ouput = %s\n", argv[indexes[i]]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The arguments after the -f should be optional and I want to list every single one that has been passed under one another...

[valentin@rpmbuild partitioner]$ ./partitioner -n 4 -f Test1 Test2 Test3 Test 4

Should be :
Number:4
File names:
Output = Test1
Output = Test2
Output = Test3
Output = Test4